# Modify request before bundle

Tags: php, symfony

I have a symfony website with many pages like

```
/page1
/page2
/page3/something/
etc...
```

In those pages, I have many time the word "pretty"

I would like that the page `/dummy/page1` returns exactly the same than `/page1` but replace all occurence of word "pretty" with the word "beautiful".
Same thing for the other pages : `/dummy/url` should always do exactly the same as `/url` but replacing "pretty" by "beautiful"

I have found an easy way to do this : In app.php , I added at the very beginning :

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/dummy') !== false) {
      $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = str_replace('/dummy','',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
      ob_start(replaceHTML($final_html))
}
```

And then simply

```
public function replaceHTML($html) {
     return str_replace('pretty','beautiful',$html);
}
```

And that work perfectly.

Now I need to make this a bundle to be able to share it.

The problem is that bundles seems to be instanciated too late, meaning after the request has been processed so changing `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` doesn't do anything at this point, and all the /dummy/url request returns 404.

Do you have any idea how I could reproduce this using a bundle ?

Comment: why not just use route prefixes?

Comment: Should be able to use a KernelEvents::REQUEST listener. http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html Be careful though, this sort of magic can make your code hard to maintain.  Might be easier to just add the routes as @RobertWade suggests.

Comment: @Cerad, You mean I should get all the possible routes, then for each route add a new "duplicate" with the /dummy prefix ?

Comment: That would be one approach.  Another would be to put all the routes in question in one file and then import the file twice using a prefix to get the dummy: http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/external_resources.html#prefixing-imported-routes But you really need to ask yourself why you need the prefix at all for testing.  Have you looked at functional testing? http://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#functional-tests

Comment: @Cerad, I added more details to what i'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create 2 routes for that page:

```
/**
 * @Route("/dummy/page1", name="route_dummy_1")
 * @Route("/page1", name="route_1")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
 ...
}
```